# Referring script stuck in a loop

Tags: javascript, dom-events

What I am trying to do is redirect a user based on their referring URL to a promo page. In the script below if someone comes from a referring URL from “example.com” they will be sent to “example.com/promo.html” When I have the script below in the page “example.com/promo.html” and it comes from a refer of “example.com” it seems to loop or continue to load the page and it never loads the page “example.com/promo.html” The script has to be in the “example.com/promo.html,” do to the page being a promo page and everyone can’t have access to the page. I assume this is due to `indexOf` and it checks for “example.com” then executes. Is there away to fix this?

```
<script language="JavaScript">
if (document.referrer.indexOf('example.com') > -1)
location.href='http://example.com/promo.html';
else
location.href='http://notfrom.example.com';
</script>
```

Comment: So, when a visitor comes to your `promo.html` page, you redirect him to that same page, thus again triggering redirection and so on? If so, remove the redirection in that case.

Comment: @Vedran But what if someone types in the promo page, how would can I check the referring domain/url? Its a promo offer page, I would like the user to access via a referring url

Comment: Or is there away to make it check the referring url then send it to the promo page? Meaning it has to come from a specific url page to access  the promo page.

Comment: Add an additional `if()`, so that the redirection to `promo.html` does not happen if you're already there. That said, both JavaScript code and the referral are easily tricked and are not something to rely on. Furthermore, a browser may be set up so that it doesn't even give you a referral information, which is another reason not to rely on it too much.

Comment: @Vedran thanks and do you have better way or suggestions on what I'm trying to accomplish.

Comment: Leaving a cookie with some random number before redirecting (both done server-side) and saving those random numbers in a session or a database, to ensure that the user came from your domain. Also, cookies may be turned off, so an additional means should be used as a safeguard (i.e., GET request). Generally, the only data you trust is your own and stuff like referral's is browser's (read user's).

Answer (score 0):

As has been mentioned in the comments the `referrer` data is not reliable, however if you do want to pursue this...

The mqost likely cause of the issue you have is that when arriving at the redirected `promo.html` it finds the referrer is from `mydomainsite.com` so it simply goes to itself creating am infinite loop.

You will need to test for that and avoid the loop by checking that `location.pathname` is not `promo.html` :

```
if (document.referrer.indexOf ('mydomainsite.com') > -1 && 
        location.pathname !== 'promo.html')
    location.href = 'http://mydomainsite.com/promo.html';
```

Comment: Thanks, I will explore this option as well. This should work for me. :)